# Tensorflow: Custom data reader using py_func

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to queue up data from an hdf5 file. Since Tensorflow does not support hdf5, I created a python function that reads examples from an hdf5 file and raises `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` when it reaches the end of the file. I then wrap this python function with `tf.py_func` and use it as an enqueue op for my queue.

This is my code:

```
import h5py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import errors
import numpy as np

def read_from_hdf5(hdf5_file, batch_size):
    h5py_handle = h5py.File(hdf5_file)

    # Check shapes from the hdf5 file so that we can set the tensor shapes
    feature_shape = h5py_handle['features'].shape[1:]
    label_shape = h5py_handle['labels'].shape[1:]

    #generator that produces examples for training. It will be wrapped by tf.pyfunc to simulate a reader
    def example_generator(h5py_handle):
        for i in xrange(0, h5py_handle['features'].shape[0]-batch_size+1, batch_size):
            features = h5py_handle['features'][i:i+batch_size]
            labels = h5py_handle['labels'][i:i+batch_size]
            yield [features, labels]
        raise errors.OutOfRangeError(node_def=None, op=None, message='completed all examples in %s'%hdf5_file)

    [features_tensor, labels_tensor] = tf.py_func(
        example_generator(h5py_handle).next,
        [],
        [tf.float32, tf.float32],
        stateful=True)

    # Set the shape so that we can infer sizes etc in later layers.
    features_tensor.set_shape([batch_size, feature_shape[0], feature_shape[1], feature_shape[2]])
    labels_tensor.set_shape([batch_size, label_shape[0]])

    return features_tensor, labels_tensor


def load_data_from_filename_list(hdf5_files, batch_size, shuffle_seed=0):
    example_list = [read_from_hdf5(hdf5_file, batch_size) for hdf5_file in hdf5_files]
    min_after_dequeue = 10000
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + (len(example_list)+1) * batch_size #min_after_dequeue + (num_threads + a small safety margin) * batch_size
    features, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch_join(example_list, batch_size, capacity=capacity, min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue, seed=shuffle_seed, enqueue_many=True)
    return features, labels, metadata
```

I expected that the `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` would be handled by the QueueRunner, however, I get the following error and the program crashes. Is it possible to do this kind of reading from a py_func, and if it is, what am I doing wrong? If not, what approach should I use instead?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 85, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tronn/datalayer.py", line 27, in example_generator
    raise errors.OutOfRangeError(node_def=None, op=None, message='completed all examples in %s'%hdf5_file)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: completed all examples
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Internal: Failed to run py callback pyfunc_13: see error log.
```

Comment: It may help if you show your code as well as the error message so people can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have added my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like exception handling in `py_func` is not supported.

Consider this code in `py_func.cc`

```
// Invokes the trampoline.
  PyObject* result = PyEval_CallObject(trampoline, args);
  Py_DECREF(args);
  if (result == nullptr) {
    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
      // TODO(zhifengc): Consider pretty-print error using LOG(STDERR).
      PyErr_Print();
    }
    return errors::Internal("Failed to run py callback ", call->token,
                            ": see error log.");
  }
```

`PyErr_Occurred` is set when there's an exception generated, so this will cause execution to throw `Failed to run py callback`.

`py_func` is an odd creature because it runs in your Python client environment. Normally when op (like reader op) fails, it which propagates from TF runtime returns not ok status to Python client, which then converts it to Python exception in `raise_exception_on_not_ok_status` (in client.py:session.run). Since `py_func` body runs in Python client, TensorFlow would need to be modified to handle `PyErr_Occurred` to insert a bad status back into TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. This seems to indicate that I cannot use py_func as a reader. What approach can I take instead?

Comment: Instead of using a reader, I would have a Python thread that enqueues your examples and then closes your queue. Then regular dequeue would raise OutOfRange error when done with examples. This [example](https://gist.github.com/jimfleming/d1118cc630f5c883223a4b4645cc2e7b) shows how to enqueue all outputs from a custom generator